# が Particle (Neutral-Descriptive) with Non-living things

Tags: particle-が

I heard that when a non-living object does an action (verbs), it always uses the「が」particle, and when I searched for examples, it seems correct, since「は」always seems to be used as contrastive. However, after I learned about the Exhaustive and Neutral「が」, I don't know why the Neutral one is used here if it's not the Exhaustive:

車が壊れた。
タイヤがパンクした。

I also learned that intransitive verbs always use「が」(Or contrastive は) as well, so, how is it related to neutral「が」?

Comment: What you heard is not true. It's not always.

Answer (score 2):

The use of が as a subject-marker is not limited to non-living entities. When a person performs an action, they are also marked with が. It can be transitive or intransitive. For example:

田中さん[*subject*] **が** 来ました。Mr Tanaka arrived. (intransitive)

田中さん[*subject*] **が** ピザを食べました。Mr Tanaka ate pizza. (transitive).

The distinction between using は (topic marker) or が (subject marker) has been discussed at length on the site.

Comment: So what is the difference between this が and は?, are they interchangeable?

Comment: That is a separate question and I suggest you do a search on the site. There are many threads dealing with that. It’s not a simple question and requires research.